# Kill Terminal/tcpdump spawned by subprocess.Popen (Python)

Tags: python, linux, shell, subprocess, popen

I have a script that is supposed to (among other things) open a new terminal window and run TCPDUMP in that terminal.  The script then waits for the user to signal they they are done (prompt waiting for 'y') in the original window.  At the point that the user enters 'y', I need to kill the TCPDUMP terminal window. Here is the setup:

```
tcp_dump_line = "\"/usr/sbin/tcpdump -nn -tttt -i " + nic
tcp_dump_line += " 'not (host ::1 and tcp and port 5432) and not (host ::1"
tcp_dump_line += " and udp and port 44954) and not (host ::1 and tcp and "
tcp_dump_line += "port 4101) and not (host 127.0.0.1 and tcp and "
tcp_dump_line += "port 4101)'\""
command = ['xfce4-terminal', '-e', tcp_dump_line,
          '-T', 'TCPDUMP']
print "[*] tcpdump command: " + ' '.join(command)

proc1 = subprocess.Popen(' '.join(command), shell=True)
running_procs.append(proc1)
```

This starts everything up fine. At program exit I run:

```
def kill_procs(running_procs):
    '''Kill processes spawned by this scripts.'''
    print "[*] Killing all startop spawned processes"
    for p in running_procs:
        print "[+] Killing PID: " + str(p.pid)
        p.kill()
```

This works for other processes I have spawned but those are direct programs and not new terminals.  From what I can gather by tracing PIDs, the new terminal is spawned by the PID of the terminal I ran the Python script in, not the PID of the Python instance itself.  So the PID that is written to `running_procs` seems to disappear after the new terminal window is opened and therefore does not work to kill the spawned terminal.

Any idea how I can exit the spawned terminal/command? I have tried without `shell=True` without luck as well.

Comment: Running `xprop _NET_WM_PID` in both the terminal where I run the Python script and the spawned terminal return the same PID.  It seems `xcfe4-terminal` is smart enough to run new instances under the same process.  So I guess I have to figure out how to determine the follow on PID of the TCPDUMP command.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up being easier to use OS commands to figure this out. Since the title of the new terminal was set to `TCPDUMP` I was able to use `pidof` to get that.

```
tcpdump_pids = subprocess.check_output(['pidof', 'tcpdump']).split()
for pid in tcpdump_pids:
    print "[+] Killing PID: " + pid
    os.kill(int(pid), signal.SIGKILL)
```